# Xamarin Android fragment not showing

Tags: c#, android, android-fragments, xamarin.android

I'm trying to load a fragment in a frame layout from my main activity.
In my resources/layout/ i got my layout for the fragment "trackMap"

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="@color/accent">
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtFragment1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:textColor="#000"
        android:text="TRACK MAP" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

and the class for TrackMapFragment:

```
public class TrackMapFragment : Android.Support.V4.App.Fragment
    {
        public override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
        {
            base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);

            // Create your fragment here
        }

        public override View OnCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState)
        {
            // Use this to return your custom view for this Fragment
            View view = inflater.Inflate(Resource.Layout.trackMap, container, false);
            return View;
        }

        public override void OnActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState)
        {
            Toast.MakeText(this.Activity, "track map fragment created", ToastLength.Short).Show();
            base.OnActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
        }
    }
```

Then in my main layout i got this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/drawer"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">
  <LinearLayout
      android:layout_height="match_parent"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:orientation="vertical">
    <include
      android:id="@+id/toolbar"
      layout="@layout/toolbar"/>
  <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/frame"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:background="#336699"/>
  </LinearLayout>
  <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
      android:id="@+id/navigation_view"
      android:layout_height="match_parent"
      android:layout_width="260dp"
      android:layout_gravity="start"
      app:headerLayout="@layout/header"
      android:background="?attr/colorAccent"
      app:menu="@menu/drawer" />
</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

And then from my main activity class (which inherits AppCompatActivity) I try to add it with the fragment manager.

```
if (_trackMapFragment == null)
{
    _trackMapFragment = new TrackMapFragment();
    var fragmentTx = SupportFragmentManager.BeginTransaction();
    fragmentTx.Add(Resource.Id.frame, _trackMapFragment);
    fragmentTx.Commit();
}
```

The toast from the fragment is showing but nothing from the actual fragment, the background doesn't change and the text from the fragment is not showing up.

Comment: your use fragment inside the fragment???

Comment: the fragment just contains a relative layout with a text view. Im really new with xamarin and im following various tutorials and the fragment markup in the guides ive seen have contained simple markup based on a relative layout only.

Comment: I have managed to get the fragment to show up. I don't know why but i removed all my fragment classes and fragment layouts. Re-added a new fragment layout simply named Fragment1, and made a new fragment class named Fragment1 and now it shows. Don't know why it did not show before.